# Unity3d on Android - debugging

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to help my son debug a little app he built using Unity3D.  It runs fine on the PC and in the editor.  When I install it on his tablet, it gives us a "Unfortunately, Wizard Battles has stopped" error after showing the Unity splash screen.

I hooked Android Studio to it and ran logcat, below is the output with the filter on Wizard Battles.  Do I need other kinds of filter to see more useful information, is anything below useful.  I am not sure why it is look for an external SD card, I can't find any references in the project.

I have tried adding some debug statements to the code, at least figure out where it is getting to before it cashes but I don't see any output.  I was sort of hoping for line number or references to modules that I could debug.  Libunity.so seems like a unity lib so I can't do much with that I assume.  The only other meaningful reference seems to be UnityPlayerActivity, but again there does not seem to be any references in the project.

Advice on how to move forward from here would be appreciated.

```
01-11 12:48:45.187 789-983/? V/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.LittleNProduction.WizardBattles
01-11 12:48:45.657 20974-20974/? D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.LittleNProduction.WizardBattles-3/libmain.so 0x42145f00
01-11 12:48:45.657 20974-20974/? D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.LittleNProduction.WizardBattles-3/libmain.so 0x42145f00
01-11 12:48:46.047 20974-21004/? W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/obb/com.LittleNProduction.WizardBattles
01-11 12:48:46.057 20974-21004/? I/Unity: ApplicationInfo com.LittleNProduction.WizardBattles version 1.0 build f628d30d-93a1-4a7f-9228-b372801dd10e
01-11 12:48:46.707 20974-21004/? W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.LittleNProduction.WizardBattles/cache
01-11 12:48:55.727 18725-18725/? I/DEBUG: pid: 20974, tid: 21025, name: UnityGfxDeviceW  >>> com.LittleNProduction.WizardBattles <<<
01-11 12:48:56.177 18725-18725/? I/DEBUG:     #14  pc 00499f24  /data/app-lib/com.LittleNProduction.WizardBattles-3/libunity.so
01-11 12:48:56.177 18725-18725/? I/DEBUG:     #15  pc 00499ed4  /data/app-lib/com.LittleNProduction.WizardBattles-3/libunity.so
01-11 12:48:56.177 18725-18725/? I/DEBUG:     #16  pc 0049ab60  /data/app-lib/com.LittleNProduction.WizardBattles-3/libunity.so
01-11 12:48:56.177 18725-18725/? I/DEBUG:     #17  pc 0049a088  /data/app-lib/com.LittleNProduction.WizardBattles-3/libunity.so
01-11 12:48:56.607 789-21068/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.LittleNProduction.WizardBattles/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
01-11 12:49:10.507 789-1212/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.LittleNProduction.WizardBattles (pid 20974) (adj 9) has died.
01-11 12:49:10.507 789-1205/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{42c2fe80 u0 com.LittleNProduction.WizardBattles/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
01-11 12:51:17.607 789-2318/? D/UsbSettingsManager: hasDefaults: com.LittleNProduction.WizardBattles FALSE
01-11 12:51:19.757 254-254/? E/installd: this /system/priv-app/SetupWizard.apk also system apk
```

Comment: Try to reboot your device.

Comment: Try also [remote debugging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityRemote5.html)

Comment: @Draco18s - perfect, at least I have debugging working now.  Thanks

Comment: well, it works in the remote debugger, just not as a stand alone :(